# Failure to convert included files from .org to .rst using pandoc

Tags: emacs, org-mode, pandoc

## Problem

I am writing blogs using Emacs org-mode. Specifically, I first create contents and get `ml.org` file and then convert it into `ml.rst` using pandoc command `pandoc -f org -t rst ml.org`.

In order to modulize the contents I wrire. I use the
following code in org-mode

```
* Supervised Learning
** Regression
#+INCLUDE: "ml/linear.org" :minlevel 3
** Classification
#+INCLUDE: "ml/logistic.org" :minlevel 3

* Unsupervised Learning
** Clustering
#+INCLUDE: "ml/kmeans.org" :minlevel 3
#+INCLUDE: "ml/spectral.org" :minlevel 3

** Dimensionality Reduction
#+INCLUDE: "ml/pca.org" :minlevel 3
#+INCLUDE: "ml/tsne.org" :minlevel 3
```

When converting this file into pdf using LaTex, the structure is correct and is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3x5v.png). However, after conversion to `ml.rst` file, **none** of these files are included.

## What I Have Done

It seems that this could be done using template feature in pandoc, but I am not sure what to do.

Could anyone help me, thank you in advance.